# Why is the implementation of the virtual method in the mock class not recognized by GMock?

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I have quite a simple setup for using `GMock (1.10.0)`. I am trying to mock an instance of Generic which is a member variable of a class named Observation. I just need to test that Generic's method `calc_gravity()` is being invoked exactly one time. Any hint would be quite appreciated. (Please ignore leaking.)

I keep getting this error message:

**no matching function for call to `MockGeneric::gmock_calc_gravity(const testing::internal::AnythingMatcher&)`**

```cpp
 class Generic {
    public:
    virtual float calc_gravity(float x, float y) { return 9.81;} // Keep it simple.
    virtual ~Generic() {}
};


class MockGeneric :public Generic {
   public:
   MOCK_METHOD(float, calc_gravity, (float, float));
};


class Observation {
    private:
    Generic* generic;
    public:
    Observation(Generic* genericPtr) : generic(genericPtr) {};
    virtual void PositionConvert(float a, float b, float c) { cout << 5.0 + generic->calc_gravity();}

    virtual ~Observation() {};
};

 TEST(PositionConverter_Test, AMethodFromGenericInvokedOneTime) {

 MockGeneric* mockGenericPtr = new MockGeneric();
 using ::testing::_;
 EXPECT_CALL(*mockGenericPtr, calc_gravity(_)).Times(1);
 Observation o(mockGenericPtr);
 o.PositionConvert(2.5, 2.5, 2.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MOCK_METHOD(float, calc_gravity, (float, float));

You should replace the line above with:

```
MOCK_METHOD2(calc_gravity, float(float, float));
```

There are other errors in your code:

> generic->calc_gravity() 
>   ... 
>   EXPECT_CALL(*mockGenericPtr, calc_gravity(_)).Times(1);

`calc_gravity` takes two arguments.

Comment: Since I am now using the 1.10.0 version of gmock, I cannot use the MOCK_METHODn format. You are right about calc_gravity(). Instead of putting two underscores, I was using only one, even though calc_gravity() takes two arguments. Now it works!

Comment: @softwarelover Great to hear!